# Cannot submit forms in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms

When I submit forms(all forms) in Drupal 7 it shows the *Your configuration settings have been saved* message, but the form values are still the same as the values before submission. I have cleared the cache but the problem still exists.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes. It was working...

Comment: Are you overriding the variables in $conf array, e.g settings.php?

Comment: @DavidThomas NO!

Comment: Any errors in the watchdog log (admin/reports/dblog)?

Comment: Are you getting the same error when you create new content?

Comment: Do you use any CDN caching on your server? This could be the problem and to resolve you would have to deal with whoever administrates this.

Comment: @hpn, you are going to have to provide more information.  Without it, the root cause could really be anything.  What do the forms do?  Webforms, or Drupal forms API?  Did you disable browser autocomplete / test multiple browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest how you can test what's happening:

1. Create custom test form with submit function.
2. Install [Xdebug](http://drupal.org/node/1846954) on your LAMP, or WAMP or MAMP
3. Than watch callstack. look what functions have been called.

Looks you've done some specific changes in your instalation.
Also try to download clear drupal instalation and check forms there.

(P.S. If you have opportunity switch to new instalation).

Answer (score 0):

Your form returns not the elements of the form. But your return part of function is something like:

```
...
return system_settings_form($form);  
}
```

if we look to this [function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7):

```
function system_settings_form($form) {
  $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save configuration'),
  );

  if (!empty($_POST) && form_get_errors()) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The settings have not been saved because of the errors.'), 'error');
  }

  $form['#submit'][] = 'system_settings_form_submit';
  // By default, render the form using theme_system_settings_form().
  if (!isset($form['#theme'])) {
    $form['#theme'] = 'system_settings_form';
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Your problem is:  $form['#submit'][] = 'system_settings_form_submit';
this adds another submit function to form. And this function saves variables through variable_set() [function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form_submit/7):

```
function system_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Exclude unnecessary elements.
  form_state_values_clean($form_state);

  foreach ($form_state['values'] as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && isset($form_state['values']['array_filter'])) {
      $value = array_keys(array_filter($value));
    }
    variable_set($key, $value);
  }

  drupal_set_message(t('The configuration options have been saved.'));
}
```

So you have to get your settings  variables with function [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7);